# SSRS. How to pass multiple select clauses from stored procedure to report?

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So I have stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_example
AS
BEGIN
-- First select clause
SELECT One, Two 
FROM Table1;

-- Second select clause
SELECT Three, Four 
FROM Table2
END
```

When I set this stored procedure as report's dataset It returns me only `One`, `Two` as Fields (from *First select clause* only).

How can I get fields from all the select clauses? In this case `One`, `Two`, `Three`, `Four`

Comment: Why not use the `UNION` ?? And if you want to different dataset from one procedure then that is not possible in `SSRS`(AFAIK). You need to create 2 separate procedures.

Comment: I can't use union because It's different datatypes and numbers of the columns

Comment: And I can't use 2 dataset's. When I'm trying to pass field from `DataSet2` I got following error: `Only fields from current dataset 'DataSet1' can be added.`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Created new *stored procedure*, added new `DataSet2` and created new table where passed fields from new `DataSet2`, after It connected both tables and for now It looks like 1 table.